# Open Street Map export to QGIS Lines not Polylines

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, spatialite

I recently updated to QGIS 2.10.1 and have found that I can no longer view .OSM files.

Before I simply dropped and dragged downloaded .OSM files into QGIS and it automatically split into four different layers: points, **Lines**, multilinesring, and multipolygons. [image: See image for line route] This no longer works.

I have tried to use the import and export topology options from the OSM plugin, however, there is no **Lines** **[image: lines]** "export type" option in the export OSM topology to spatiaLite box. These means I am now missing a large amount of my road, footpath, ect data (I am working with rural areas which will not receive much attention with the OSM community) which is obviously saved as a line not a polyline.

Is there anyway to export line data?

Comment: Do you have the QuickOSM plugin installed?

Comment: I didn't but now that I do its working perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the QuickOSM plugin installed I have no problems